# ReactJS table in dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs, button, drop-down-menu

I'm using ReactJS. 
I am using reactstrap table.
I am using dropdown menu in table row. 
But when I click the dropdown menu in the table, all the menus are opened.
I want the dropdown that I selected with dropdown to be opened in the table.

How do I fix this?

So if I click on the table, that menu will open.

[image]
[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import withAuth from "../../components/helpers/withAuth";
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardHeader,
  Col,
  Pagination,
  PaginationItem,
  PaginationLink,
  Row,
  Table,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  ModalFooter,
  Dropdown,
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownToggle,
  Alert
} from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Input from "reactstrap/es/Input";
import ButtonDropdown from "reactstrap/es/ButtonDropdown";
class CustomerDebt extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.domain = `http://127.0.0.1:8000`;
    this.state = {
      dropdownOpen: false,
      modal: false,
      isLoaded: true,
      items: [],         
      selectedItem:{ }   
    };
    this.dropdownToggle = this.dropdownToggle.bind(this);
    this.debtModalForm = this.debtModalForm.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmitUpdate = this.handleSubmitUpdate.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmitCreate = this.handleSubmitCreate.bind(this);
  }
  //Customer debts unmounts - refresh problem
  abortController = new AbortController();
  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.abortController.abort();
  };
  //Get customer debts
  async componentDidMount() {
    //Müşteriye ait tüm borçları listele
    await fetch(
        `${this.domain}/api/debt/list?customer=` +
        this.props.customerInfo.customer.id,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("id_token")}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }
    )
        .then(res => {
          if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
          } else {
            return res.json().then(err => Promise.reject(err));
          }
        })
        .then(json => {
          this.setState({
            items: json
          });
          this.abortController.abort();
          // console.log(json)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          //console.log('request failed:', error);
          return error;
        });
  }
  //Customer debt update
  async handleSubmitUpdate (value) {
    await fetch(`${this.domain}/api/debt/update/`+ value.id, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("id_token")}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user: this.props.account_profile.profile.profile.id, //this.props.user.user_id,
        customer: this.props.customerInfo.customer.id,
        debtKey: this.props.customerInfo.customer.customerKey,
        createduserKey: this.props.account_profile.profile.profile.userKey,
        totalDebt: this.state.totalDebt,
        receivedAmount: this.state.receivedAmount,
        description: this.state.description,
        paymentDate: this.state.paymentDate
      })
    })
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
          this.componentDidMount();
          //console.log(json)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
  //Customer debt insert
  async handleSubmitCreate (value) {
    console.log("burası insert alanı");
    console.log(value);
    await fetch(`${this.domain}/api/debt/create`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("id_token")}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user: this.props.account_profile.profile.profile.id, //this.props.user.user_id,
        customer: this.props.customerInfo.customer.id,
        debtKey: this.props.customerInfo.customer.customerKey,
        createduserKey: this.props.account_profile.profile.profile.userKey,
        totalDebt: this.state.totalDebt,
        receivedAmount: this.state.receivedAmount,
        description: this.state.description,
        paymentDate: this.state.paymentDate
      })
    })
        .then(response => {
//          console.log(response );
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
          this.componentDidMount();
          //console.log(json)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
  debtModalForm (value) {
    console.log( value);
    if (value === "newRecord") {
      this.setState( prevState =>({
        modal: !prevState.modal, // modal durumunu ayarla
      }))
    } else {
      console.log(value);
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        modal: !prevState.modal,
        selectedItem: value,  
        //Hata oluşmaması için state aktarıyorum
        user: value.user,
        customer: value.customer,
        debtKey: value.debtKey,
        createduserKey: value.createduserKey,
        totalDebt: value.totalDebt,
        receivedAmount: value.receivedAmount,
        description: value.description,
        paymentDate: value.paymentDate
      }));
    }
  }
  //text handleChange
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }
  //dropdown toggle menu
  dropdownToggle = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen,
    }));
  };
  render() {
    const { isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    //console.log(this.props.customerInfo.customer);
    //console.log(this.props.account_profile.profile.profile.userKey);
    //console.log(this.props.customerInfo.customer.customerKey );
    //If customerID -1 return
    if (this.props.customerInfo.customer.id === "-1") {
      return <Redirect to={"/customerlist"} />;
    }
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
          <div className={"animated fadeIn container-fluid"}>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Card>
                  <CardHeader>
                    <Dropdown
                        isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen}
                        toggle={this.dropdownToggle }
                        onClick={ ()=> console.log("üst menü tıklandı")}
                    >
                      <DropdownToggle caret className={"float-right"}>
                        İşlemler
                      </DropdownToggle>
                      <DropdownMenu>
                        <DropdownItem
                            color="info"
                            onClick={ this.debtModalForm.bind(this,"newRecord") }> newRecord
                          {
                            <Modal
                                isOpen={this.state.modal}
                                toggle={this.debtModalForm}
                                backdrop={"static"}
                            >
                              <ModalHeader toggle={this.debtModalForm}>
                                { this.props.customerInfo.customer.id } customer number -new
                              </ModalHeader>
                              <ModalBody>
                                <Row>
                                  <Col xs="2">Borç</Col>
                                  <Col xs="6">
                                    <Input
                                        type={"text"}
                                        placeholder={"Borç"}
                                        name={"totalDebt"}
                                        defaultValue={this.state.totalDebt}
                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    />
                                  </Col>
                                </Row>
                              </ModalBody>
                              <ModalFooter>
                                <Button
                                    color="primary"
                                    onClick={ this.handleSubmitCreate.bind(this)}
                                > Yeni Kayıt
                                </Button>{" "}
                                <Button
                                    color="secondary"
                                    onClick={this.debtModalForm}
                                > Kapat
                                </Button>
                              </ModalFooter>
                            </Modal>
                          }
                        </DropdownItem>
                      </DropdownMenu>
                    </Dropdown>
                    <i className="fa fa-align-justify" /> Müşteri Borcu
                  </CardHeader>
                  <CardBody>
                    <Table hover bordered striped responsive size="sm">
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th width={"10"} />
                        <th width={"15"}>No</th>
                        <th style={{ display: "none" }}>User</th>
                        <th style={{ display: "none" }}>Key</th>
                        <th style={{ display: "none" }}>CreatedUserKey</th>
                        <th width={"40"}>Borç Miktarı</th>
                        <th width={"40"}>Alınan miktar</th>
                        <th scope={"row"}>Açıklama</th>
                        <th width={"20"}>Ödeme tarihi</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      {items.map(item => (
                          <tr key={item.id}>

                            <td>
                              <ButtonDropdown
                                  isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen}
                                  toggle={this.dropdownToggle}
                                  onClick={() => console.log(item.id)}>
                                <DropdownToggle caret>
                                  Process
                                </DropdownToggle>
                                <DropdownMenu>
                                  <DropdownItem >Header</DropdownItem>
                                  <DropdownItem >Action</DropdownItem>
                                  <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
                                  <DropdownItem divider />
                                  <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
                                </DropdownMenu>
                              </ButtonDropdown>
                            </td>
                            <td>{item.id}</td>
                            <td style={{ display: "none" }}>{item.user}</td>
                            <td style={{ display: "none" }}>{item.debtKey}</td>
                            <td style={{ display: "none" }}> {item.createduserKey} </td>
                            <td>{item.totalDebt}</td>
                            <td>{item.receivedAmount}</td>
                            <td>{item.description}</td>
                            <td>{new Date(item.paymentDate).toLocaleString()}</td>
                          </tr>
                      ))}
                      </tbody>
                    </Table>
                    <nav>
                      <Pagination>
                        <PaginationItem>
                          <PaginationLink previous tag="button">
                            Önceki
                          </PaginationLink>
                        </PaginationItem>
                        <PaginationItem active>
                          <PaginationLink tag="button">1</PaginationLink>
                        </PaginationItem>
                        <PaginationItem>
                          <PaginationLink tag="button">2</PaginationLink>
                        </PaginationItem>
                        <PaginationItem>
                          <PaginationLink tag="button">3</PaginationLink>
                        </PaginationItem>
                        <PaginationItem>
                          <PaginationLink tag="button">4</PaginationLink>
                        </PaginationItem>
                        <PaginationItem>
                          <PaginationLink next tag="button">
                            Sonraki
                          </PaginationLink>
                        </PaginationItem>
                        <PaginationItem>
                          <Button
                              color="info"
                              onClick={ this.debtModalForm.bind(this, "newRecord") }> Yeni Kayıt
                            {
                              <Modal
                                  isOpen={this.state.modal}
                                  toggle={this.debtModalForm}
                                  backdrop={"static"}
                              >
                                <ModalHeader toggle={this.debtModalForm}>
                                  { this.props.customerInfo.customer.id } numaralı müşteri - Yeni Kayıt
                                </ModalHeader>
                                <ModalBody>
                                  <Row>
                                    <Col xs="2">Borç</Col>
                                    <Col xs="6">
                                      <Input
                                          type={"text"}
                                          placeholder={"Borç"}
                                          name={"totalDebt"}
                                          defaultValue={this.state.totalDebt}
                                          onChange={this.handleChange}
                                      />
                                    </Col>
                                  </Row>
                                  <Row>
                                    <Col xs="2">Alınan</Col>
                                    <Col xs="6">
                                      <Input
                                          type={"text"}
                                          placeholder={"Alınan"}
                                          name={"receivedAmount"}
                                          defaultValue={this.state.receivedAmount}
                                          onChange={this.handleChange}
                                      />
                                    </Col>
                                  </Row>
                                  <Row>
                                    <Col xs="2">Açıklama</Col>
                                    <Col xs="6">
                                      <Input
                                          type={"textarea"}
                                          placeholder={"Açıklama"}
                                          name={"description"}
                                          defaultValue={this.state.description}
                                          onChange={this.handleChange}
                                          rows={"2"}
                                      />
                                    </Col>
                                  </Row>
                                  <Row>
                                    <Col xs="2">Ödeme tarihi</Col>
                                    <Col xs="6">
                                      <Input
                                          type={"date"}
                                          placeholder={"Ödeme tarihi"}
                                          name={"paymentDate"}
                                          defaultValue={this.state.selectedItem.paymentDate}
                                          onChange={this.handleChange}
                                      />
                                    </Col>
                                  </Row>
                                </ModalBody>
                                <ModalFooter>
                                  <Button
                                      color="primary"
                                      onClick={ this.handleSubmitCreate.bind(this)}
                                  > Yeni Kayıt
                                  </Button>{" "}
                                  <Button
                                      color="secondary"
                                      onClick={this.debtModalForm}
                                  > Kapat
                                  </Button>
                                </ModalFooter>
                              </Modal>
                            }
                          </Button>
                        </PaginationItem>
                      </Pagination>
                    </nav>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return state;
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withAuth(CustomerDebt));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state.dropdownOpen` is being used for every dropdown in the component.  You need to define a different state variable for each individual dropdown so you have control over each of them independently.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
Just create a separate 'Dropdown' component.

```js
/** @format */
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {
  ButtonDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
} from 'reactstrap'

const Dropdown = ({ buttonDropdownName, actionsArray }) => {
  const [dropdownOpen, setOpen] = useState(false)

  const toggle = () => setOpen(!dropdownOpen)

  return (
    <ButtonDropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle} color='warning'>
      <DropdownToggle caret>{buttonDropdownName}</DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        {actionsArray.map((action) => (
          <DropdownItem onClick={action.function}>{action.name}</DropdownItem>
        ))}
      </DropdownMenu>
    </ButtonDropdown>
  )
}

export default Dropdown
```